# Unable to query each record in my Elasticsearch after importing data from RDBMS from logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using logstash to import data from ms sql server to elastic search and I can see all the data in the console when I run the config file. But when I query on my data, it gives me "null". Here is my config file.

```
input {
       jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/krishna.shah/Krishna/sqljdbc4-chs-4.0.2206.100.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=master"
    jdbc_user => "**"
    jdbc_password => "****@123"
    statement => "select * FROM ****g"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
    jdbc_page_size => "50000"
  }
}


output {
 elasticsearch{
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "krishna"
    document_type => "docc"
    document_id => "%{id}"
    sniffing => true
    user => "**"
    password => "****"
    } stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
```

I tried to query:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/krishna/docc/_search?q=auditcolumn:NPI&pretty'
```

It gives me:

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

But there is actually a record present in RDBMS and is seen in the console when I run my config file of logstash. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What is total count of records in ES index , is it 0? or when running the above query hitss are null?  curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/krishna/docc/_search check how many records are there in krishna index

Comment: @prasad kp :Yes, I can see data coming in my console when I run :-bin/logstash -f (path of config file), and also it gives me this result in ES tool(chrome extension):- {
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "krishna",
        "_type": "data1",
        "_id": "%{id}",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          ..... }}}}}

Comment: But the data which come in console is recursive and it keeps repeating.